# DBPedia: extracting data to csv -> Missing <namespace-iri-string> error message

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying to extract the birthyear of veterans from a DBPedia database using SPARQL and order them by their birthyear.

Needless to say I'm a History student and we have to do this course, I do not have much understanding of what it is I'm supposed to do.

I tried to see if I could give some other informations, but did not manage to do a thing.

Thanks in advance for all the help I can get.

When I follow the instructions given by our professor:

```
PREFIX dbr: PREFIX dbp: PREFIX dbo: SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?birthDate
WHERE {
?s ?p dbr:Veteran;
dbo:birthDate ?birthDate
}
order by ?birthDate
```

All I get is the following error:

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 5: Missing <namespace-iri-string> in PREFIX declaration at 'PREFIX' before 'dbp:'

SPARQL query:
#output-format:auto
define sql:signal-void-variables 1
define input:default-graph-uri <http://dbpedia.org/>
PREFIX dbr: 
PREFIX dbp: 
PREFIX dbo:

SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?birthDate
WHERE {
?s ?p dbr:Veteran;
dbo:birthDate ?birthDate
}
order by ?birthDate
```

EDIT:

I found the issue myself, I was missing the URI for `dbo`, `dbr` and `dbp`.

Now I do however have another error. It's a syntax error, which I tried to compare to similar codes but could not find the answer.

OUTPUT:

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 9: syntax error at 'dbo:birthDate' before '?birthDate'
```

Comment: The input is as follows: 

PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?birthDate
WHERE {
{?s ?p dbr:Veteran: dbo:birthDate ?birthDate}
}
order by ?birthDate

Comment: the separator of triple patterns is either a dot or a semicolon for the short form reusing a subject, but clearly not a colon. The error message also highlights the part where you should have double-checked your query then. Use `?s ?p dbr:Veteran ; dbo:birthDate ?birthDate .` or just write `?s ?p dbr:Veteran . ?s dbo:birthDate ?birthDate .`

Comment: It's not at all clear what "The input" comment is meant to replace in your question. I suggest you fully edit your question, to make your "new" query more clearly the current focus, if indeed you leave any trace of the original ... or just delete this question, and ask an entirely new question, starting from your current understanding.